# SQL and relational algebra

Tags: sql

I've got some problems which I can't work out. Here is the scheme:

```
sch(branch)=(branch_Nr,town) (Key: branch_Nr)
sch(account)=(account_Nr,ballance) (Key: account_Nr)
sch(manages)=(account_Nr,branch_Nr) (Key: account_Nr, branch_Nr)
sch(customer)=(customer_Nr,Name,street,place) (Key: customer_Nr)
sch(mentors)=(branch_Nr,customer_Nr) (Key: customer_Nr)
sch(opens)=(customer_Nr,account_Nr) (Key: account_Nr)
```

the task is to get with relational algebra: get all customers with 2 different accounts. I tried the solution:

```
πname(Customer) |X| σ k1!=k2 (πk1 <- account_Nr (account) X πk2 <-     account_Nr (account))
```

But this doesnt work does it? I feel like im missing sth here.

Second task is: to get 2 customers with two different accounts, which are managed by different branches in SQL:
I tried it with:

```
CREATE VIEW N AS
SELECT account_Nr
FROM account
GROUP BY accountNr
HAVING TOTAL = 2
```

With this I wanted to make it more structured so I used a view before I actually use the real selection task. But im kinda stuck here already. The problem is that I want everybody who got 2 accounts which are at different branches. This means that he can still have more than 2 accounts. But with this I ignore that. And i am not so sure how to proceed after that as well. These are one of the problems I try to prepare myself for an upcoming test. I would really appreciate help! kinda stuck here.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not CS homework. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com for CS theory.

Comment: I even wrote what i attempted.. it is not homework, it is a task i searched myself to better understand it and to train myself. this comment was by no means helpful. even if you dont wanna post code, you could give a general direction.. how i could come to a solution..

Comment: You should probably add the appropriate tag for the dialect of SQL that you're using - you're unlikely to attract good answers without it.

Comment: you're doing cs theory, this site is for practical stuff. like I said, try the CS SE site.

Comment: One way to get the desired result is to join `customer/opens/manages` and then do a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT branch_Nr) >= 2`

Comment: thx that in fact helps me :)

Comment: In English language sentences end with a single "." and not ".."

Comment: you saw two ".." and you write that stpuid comment? aaaalrightyyy..